# Using Selenium IDE to change an Attribute's value

Tags: extjs, selenium, selenium-ide

Using Selenium IDE

Is it possible to change the following

```
<div class="x-grid-checkheader"> </div>
```

to

```
<div class="x-grid-checkheader x-grid-checkheader-checked"> </div>
```

if so, please describe how.

I have researched and can not find a way to modify an attribute's value using Selenium IDE as described above.

Comment: You can try executing JavaScript code `document.querySelectorAll('div.x-grid-checkheader')[0].className += ' test';` or something alike.

Comment: You should be thinking about this from a user perspective...what would a user have to click to get that to happen? If the user cannot, then whilst you can still hack about to get it to work, Selenium isn't intended to do something that a user cannot.